# getting error while checking the network state in android retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to check the network state to manage the offline support in the application using retrofit to store cache of `preloaded` responses. here is my code

```
 public static Interceptor provideOfflineCacheInterceptor ()
    {
        return new Interceptor()
        {
            @Override
            public Response intercept (Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException
            {
                Request request = chain.request();

                if ( !AdeptAndroid.hasNetwork() )
                {
                    CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl.Builder()
                            .maxStale( 7, TimeUnit.DAYS )
                            .build();

                    request = request.newBuilder()
                            .cacheControl( cacheControl )
                            .build();
                }

                return chain.proceed( request );
            }
        };
    }
```

in this portion where i am checking the network state i am getting null pointer  exception here.

```
 if ( !AdeptAndroid.hasNetwork() )
```

here is `AdepAndroid` class

```
public class AdeptAndroid extends Application {

    private static AdeptAndroid instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        instance = this;

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        {
            Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());
        }

        Timber.i("Creating our Application");
    }

    public static AdeptAndroid getInstance ()
    {
        return instance;
    }

    public static boolean hasNetwork ()
        {
            return instance.checkIfHasNetwork();
    }

    public boolean checkIfHasNetwork()
    {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

in this class i am simply checking the network state and getting error here as `nullpointerException` here.

```
 public static boolean hasNetwork ()
            {
                return instance.checkIfHasNetwork();
        }
```

please help to solve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You mean `AdeptAndroid.getInstance().hasNetwork()` ?

It seems that you are calling class itself, not a instance. So, call instance.

---

Update2: Your code need to be modified like this.

```
public static Interceptor provideOfflineCacheInterceptor ()
{
    return new Interceptor()
    {
        @Override
        public Response intercept (Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException
        {
            Request request = chain.request();

            // You need context at this point. Your Application can be called by getApplicationContext(), not by custom getInstance().
            if ( !((AdeptAndroid)context.getApplicationContext()).hasNetwork() ) 
            {
                CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl.Builder()
                        .maxStale( 7, TimeUnit.DAYS )
                        .build();

                request = request.newBuilder()
                        .cacheControl( cacheControl )
                        .build();
            }

            return chain.proceed( request );
        }
    };
}
```

And your Application should be like this:

```
public class AdeptAndroid extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());
        }

        Timber.i("Creating our Application");
    }

    public boolean hasNetwork () {
        return checkIfHasNetwork();
    }

    public boolean checkIfHasNetwork() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

Comment: please write a sample code for that for better understanding

Comment: return instance.checkIfHasNetwork(); this line is showing error @Stanley

Comment: Oh `AdeptAndroid ` is Application and you want to user this as Singleton?

Comment: what are you trying to say ?

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: getting class cast exception here  ....   if (  !((AdeptAndroid)getApplicationContext()).hasNetwork())

Comment: @S.Hashmi Then, define your application name to AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: it is just a class how can i define this in the android manifest?